# Pass along $(this) from function to function

Tags: jquery, function, this

I want to be able to declare a function that I can use with any selector or method, therefore I thought it could be done like the following, but it does not work!

Why is that? :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('img').hover(function(){
        imageClass();
    });

    function imageClass() {
        var thisClass = $(this).attr('class');
        console.log(thisClass)
    }

});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass `$(this)` from hover event as an `argument`, All you need is to change the `imageClass method to receive a parameter`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('img').hover(function(){
        imageClass($(this));
    });

    function imageClass(obj) {
        var thisClass = obj.attr('class');
        console.log(thisClass)
    }

});
```

Comment: `$(obj)` is an overkill. Just `obj` is enough

Comment: You don't need to wrap obj with the $() again in the imageClass function, since you passed it as a jQuery object already.

Comment: It worked nicely :) - I also noticed and unwrapped the obj from $(), so I do have a little JS understanding, but not quite the full overview yet :) - Thanks alot. Can you tell me the pros and cons of moving the imageClass function outside the .ready function?

Comment: @afcdesign: there is no any significant differences. Other than it won't be available outside - I cannot say any important one.

Comment: .ready executes when the all the elements of document are ready and could be accessed more about .ready http://api.jquery.com/ready/ As  zerkms said there is no significant difference as you are calling it from .ready

Comment: Thanks, that is also what I thought!

Answer (score 0):

This, however, will also work:

```
$('img').hover(imageClass);

function imageClass() {
    var thisClass = $(this).attr('class');
    console.log(thisClass)
}
```

And one more option:

```
$('img').hover(imageClass);

function imageClass(e) {
    var thisClass = $(e.target).attr('class');
    console.log(thisClass)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [jQuery.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/). It will allow you to pass `this`

If you are unable to figure out let me know.

Comment: In this case you don't even need `$.proxy()`. `imageClass.call(this);` will do the work. Whereas `$.proxy()` is suitable in the case when you need to pass a reference to the function with the predefined scope (which isn't the case here).